# How can I auto generate date with SpringBoot+MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot to access my MongoDB database. I have an entity called User and a UserRepository to have CRUD operations. I would like that each time I add a user, it also add a creation and update date.
With traditionnal SQL database and JPA, I would use @PrePersist and @PreUpdate.

What would be the best way to do it in this case ?

I paste my User code below (but it is super simple) :

```
public class User {

    @Id
    public String id;

    public String username;

    public String password;

}
```

And the UserRepository :

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path="users")
    public interface UsersRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>{

    public User findByUsername(String username);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to enable auditing feature and update `User` domain object.

- Add `joda-time` maven dependency.

  `<dependency>
     <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.9</version>
  </dependency>`
- Enable auditing support in spring configuration.

  `<mongo:auditing />`
- Add 2 more properties in `User`.

```java
@CreatedDate
private DateTime createdOn;

@LastModifiedDate
private DateTime updatedOn;
```

Please note, `createdOn` only gets added for the first time when Id field is set.

Comment: It looks like what I am looking for. I did not know Joda. I will try this.